# Не работает Acf Flexible на странице магазина, на теме Storefront (WooCommerce)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины, acf

Не работает Acf Flexible на странице магазина, на теме Storefront (WooCommerce). Код написан в файле archive-product.php от которого наследуется страница Shop. Вот код (который работает на всех других страницах) которым я вывожу flexible блоки:

```
if( get_field('flexible') ):
    while ( has_sub_field('flexible') ) :

        get_template_part('templates/' . get_row_layout());

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Контент блока добавлен в редакторе самой страницы, что является довольно странным потому что блоки от ACF появились в админке, а в коде данные из них получить нельзя, прикрепляю скриншот заполнения блока:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ACF поле Flexible должно выводиться для каждой страницы, этот параметр выбран в настройках поля Flexible. Прикрепляю скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также исключите проблему не существование файла который вызывается функцией get_template_part (). Прикрепляю скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там нужно вторым параметром прокинуть ID shop страницы, можете прокинуть [get_queried_object_id()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_queried_object_id) вторым параметром в `get_field()` и `has_sub_field()`. Либо можете использовать `get_option('woocommerce_shop_page_id')`

Comment: [Всеровно не работает](https://ibb.co/SmQHypp) - по силке скрин как написал код